# Why should I ever curry functions in Python

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming, currying

I have used Haskell in the past so I understand it's usage and benefits there. But in Python, I'm struggling to see why I would ever want to curry (besides stylistic preferences). Posts here and sites like [this](https://www.codespeedy.com/currying-function-in-python-and-its-advantages/) usually mention that currying allows for function re-usability but I don't see it. The common example of:

```
def f(a, b):
   return a + b
```

vs

```
def f(a):
   def g(b):
      return a + b
   return g
```

doesn't seem to showcase any real benefit. In fact, the function nesting definition and even calling `f(a)(b)` seems less clear then the 'standard' function definition. Can someone provide an example where currying showcases some net benefit?

Comment: https://javascript.info/currying-partials Here's a decent example. I think mostly you're correct, there are few places were currying is a good idea. I've never seen one outside of a classroom.

Comment: It can make delegation simpler. You need to say, make an HTTP request to an endpoint multiple times with different data, timeouts, etc. So you can either write a bespoke function that delegates to `requests.post` or you can partially apply the parameters. IDK I use `functools.partial` all the time, e.g. on database conn calls. Really though the way this is written seems kinda opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

I often curry functions when using the `multiprocessing` module for running a function in parallel. Its [`pool.map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) requires the function to accept a single argument (the data being worked on) but I often need additional parameters that are invariant. For this, I create a partial version of the function using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```py
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool

def do_work(constant_param, variable_param):
    context = setup_spam(constant_param)
    return calc_eggs(context, variable_param)

pool = Pool()
inputs = [1, 2, 3]
partial_func = partial(do_work, "potatoes")
results = pool.map(partial_func, inputs)
```

This effectively does the following calls in parallel:

```
do_work("potatoes", 1)
do_work("potatoes", 2)
do_work("potatoes", 3)
```

Comment: So your use case here stems from the fact that your fn of interest expects another function with only 1 parameter. However, you need more than 1 degree of freedom hence the partial fn. This makes sense but this scenario seems to be a bit rare.

Comment: @Kiwibreeder that depends on what you usually code. Almost every time I want to run a function in parallel it contains nontrivial computation that requires multiple parameters.

Comment: @Kiwibreeder "writing python code" is not an atomic activity. Python is used for everything from webapps to data science to unix scripting to... the code *I* write benefits greatly from `functools.partial`. Doesn't mean that one type of code is better or worse or that what you're doing for your use case is wrong. Also doesn't mean that the concept is useless.